# How to create a generic component in TypeScript with a prop that receives a HTML element or a Component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to create a component that can be a normal HTML anchor element or a `Link` component. This is how far I came:

```js
type AnchorProps<Component extends 'a' | typeof Link> = ComponentProps<Component> & {
    children: ReactNode,
    color?: 'blue' | 'red',
    component?: Component,
};
const Anchor = <Component extends 'a' | typeof Link, >({
    children,
    color = 'blue',
    // error TS2322: Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'Component | (ComponentClass<any, any> & Component) | (FunctionComponent<any> & Component)'.
    component: Component = 'a',
}: AnchorProps<Component>) => {
    // error TS2322: Type '{ children: string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ... 47 more ... | undefined; className: string; }' is not assignable to type '(IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<Component, any>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<...>) | (IntrinsicAttributes & LibraryManagedAttributes<...>)'.
    // Type '{ children: string | number | boolean | {} | ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | ... 47 more ... | undefined; className: string; }' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<FunctionComponent<any> & Component, any>'.
    return <Component className={`anchor ${color}`}>{children}</Component>;
};

export default Anchor;
```

Any idea on how to fix the errors in the comments?